# Basic vectors in two dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If $a$ and $b$ are vectors such that $||a|| =4$, $||b|| = 5$, and $||a+b|| = 7$, then find $||2a-3b||$.

I found that $||2a||=8$ and $||3b||=15$ using the definition of a norm, but I don't know where to go from here. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you in an inner product space? If so, is it a real inner product space?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\|2a - 3b\|^2 = (2a - 3b)^2 = 4a^2 + 9b^2 - 12a\cdot b = 4\|a\|^2 + 9\|b\|^2 -12 a \cdot b$$

and

$$\|a+b\|^2 = (a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2 a \cdot b = \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 + 2 a \cdot b$$